# How do I remove this Polyline of the map route?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi guys so what I'm trying to do is create a button that triggers the findRandomPlace() func. Its suppose to show me a random place in places array. When it gives me a random place it should draw the polyline from the source to destination (which it does) and then if I don't like that place I can click the Button again and it should show me another place (which it does), the problem is the polyline from the last place. I don't know how to remove it.

```
let route = response.routes[0]
self.Map.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
```

The above code is what draws the polyline but im not sure what I can do to remove it.
Thanks in advance if you could pitch in any ideas.

```
var previousIndex:Int = 999999
func findRandomPlace() {//need an if statement to check if its near u or in the area
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(places.count)))

    if randomIndex != previousIndex {//Makes sure next place can't be current place
        previousIndex = randomIndex

        Name.text = (places[randomIndex][0])
        Description.text = (places[randomIndex][1])


        //Draw Direction Line
        let positionX:Double? = Double(places[randomIndex][2])
        let positionY:Double? = Double(places[randomIndex][3])

        let sourceCoordinates = manager.location?.coordinate
        let destinationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(positionX!, positionY!)
        print(sourceCoordinates!)

        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinates)

        let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        let destinationItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = sourceItem
        directionRequest.destination = destinationItem
        directionRequest.transportType = .walking

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
            response, error in
            //Draw Polyline and Zoom Into It
            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("error")
                }
                return
            }
            let route = response.routes[0]
            self.Map.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.Map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
        })
        } else {

            findRandomPlace()
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.
I am ashamed it took so long but I'm happy I found out in the end.

```
self.Map.removeOverlays(self.Map.overlays)
```